# How to calculate a direct mapped chace capacity with tag and valid bits?

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-cache

I've seen some very useful posts about this, but none took into consideration both the tag and valid bits. This is a question I took from a notebook in my computer engineering course.

> Consider a machine with a direct mapped cache, with 1 Byte blocks and 7 bits for
>   the tag. This machine has a RAM with 2 KB capacity. Calculate the cache's total capcity, counting the tag bits and valid bits.

Breaking a cache into parts, I have the **tag bits**, **set index** and **block offset**.

I already know I have 7 tag bits, but then I'm really not sure how to calculate the rest, because in this type of question we are usually given the words per block. I think the offset is 3, because 2^3 (8 bit blocks).

I feel like the question itself doesn't give enough, shouldn't it be stated how the system address is (byte/word addressable)? Also, is the RAM capacity relevant to the question at hand?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless specified otherwise, addresses are always byte adresses (and with a cache with 1B/block, any other choice would not make sense)

Ram size is relevant as it indicates addresse width.

Cache blocs are 1 byte -> offset=0b (offset indicates byte position in block and only 1 possible position).

RAM is 2kB (2^11) -> address is 11 bits

Adress width=Tag with+Index width+Offset width

Tag=7b, Address=11b, Offset=0b -> index=4b

Cache is direct Mapped -> Cache size for data=number of blocks * block size = 2^(index size)*(Block size)

-> Cache Size (data) = 2^4*1B=16B

Block associated with Tag(7b) + 1 valid bit -> 1 extra B for control per block

Total cache size = 16 block each with 1B data and 1B control -> 32B

Comment: Thank you, this was very clear and helpful. Yes, I considered it byte addressable, as it made the most sense,but I started seeing a lot of similar questions that said it should be specified, thanks for explaining that.